# One row for department and customer with sum of administration and productive work per month

Tags: database, oracle

I have a problem with SQL query. 
I'll exmplain my problem with the example:
I have four tables:

TABLE DEPARTMENT:

```
-----------------
ID   DEPARTMENT
--- -------------
 1  Marketing
 2  IT Department
 3  Human resources
...
```

TABLE CUSTOMER:

```
-------------------------
ID   CUSTOMER
--- ---------------------
 1  Coffee world
...
```

TABLE ADMINISTRATION WORK

```
--------------------------
DATE              Customer       Department           SUM_ADMINISTRATION_WORK
----------------- -------------- -------------------- -----------------------
SEP-2017          Coffee world    Marketing                                 25
OCT-2017          Coffee world    Marketing                              11.42
OCT-2017          Coffee world    IT Department                             97
OCT-2017          Coffee world    Human resources                        40.58
...
```

TABLE PRODUCTIVE WORK

```
-------------------------
DATE              Customer       Department           SUM_PRODUCTIVE_WORK
----------------- -------------- -------------------- -------------------
SEP-2017          Coffee world    Marketing                            115
OCT-2017          Coffee world    IT Department                          5
OCT-2017          Coffee world    Marketing                            160
...
```

I want to display one row for department and customer with sum of administration and productive work per month.

```
DATE_ACTIVITY     Customer             Department           SUM_ADMINISTRATION_WORK SUM_PRODUCTIVE_WORK EFFORTS_DURATION
----------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------------------- ------------------- ----------------
SEP-2017          Coffee world          Marketing                                 25                1.91            26.91
OCT-2017          Coffee world          IT Department                             97                 .08            97.08
OCT-2017          Coffee world          Marketing                              11.42                2.66            14.08
...
```

The problem is that I need to display also department Human resources where sum of productive work is 0.

```
DATE_ACTIVITY     Customer             Department           SUM_ADMINISTRATION_WORK SUM_PRODUCTIVE_WORK EFFORTS_DURATION
----------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------------------- ------------------- ----------------
SEP-2017          Coffee world          Marketing                                 25                1.91            26.91
OCT-2017          Coffee world          IT Department                             97                 .08            97.08
OCT-2017          Coffee world          Marketing                              11.42                2.66            14.08
OCT-2017          Coffee world          Human resources                        40.58                   0            40.58
```

Query that I use:

```
select 
   aw.date_activity,
   c.customer "Customer",
   d.department "Department", 
   SUM(NVL(aw.administration_work,0)) as "SUM_ADMINISTRATION_WORK",
   SUM(NVL(pw.productive_work,0)) as "SUM_PRODUCTIVE_WORK",
   nvl(TRUNC(NVL(aw.administration_work,0) + NVL(pw.productive_work,0),2),0) as "EFFORTS_DURATION"
from customer c
   join (
     select 
       id_customer, 
       id_dep,
       to_char("DATE", 'MON-YYYY') date_activity,
       TRUNC(sum(duration),2) as administration_work
     from 
       administration_work aw
     group by 
        to_char("DATE", 'MON-YYYY'), id_customer, id_dep
   ) aw on c.id = aw.id_customer
   join (
     select 
       id_customer,  
       id_dep,
       to_char("DATE", 'MON-YYYY') date_activity,
       TRUNC(sum(duration),2) as productive_work
     from 
       productive_work pw
     group by 
       to_char("DATE", 'MON-YYYY'), id_customer, id_dep
     ) pw on c.id = pw.id_customer
   join department d on (d.id = aw.id_dep and d.id = pw.id_dep)
   where
       c.id = (select id from customer where customer = 'Coffee world')
       and aw.date_activity = pw.date_activity
   group by aw.date_activity, c.customer, d.department, aw.administration_work, pw.productive_work
   order by aw.date_activity desc, d.department
   ;
```

Do you have any idea how to fix my problem?

Thanks for every advice.

Comment: This could be done with window functions.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Where I should use windows function? In query or subquery? I don't have lot of experience with window function.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test but try this one:

```
select 
   aw.date_activity,
   c.customer "Customer",
   d.department "Department", 
   SUM(NVL(aw.administration_work,0)) as "SUM_ADMINISTRATION_WORK",
   SUM(NVL(pw.productive_work,0)) as "SUM_PRODUCTIVE_WORK",
   nvl(TRUNC(NVL(aw.administration_work,0) + NVL(pw.productive_work,0),2),0) as "EFFORTS_DURATION"
from customer 
   join (
     select 
       id_customer, 
       id_dep,
       to_char("DATE", 'MON-YYYY') date_activity,
       TRUNC(sum(duration),2) as administration_work
     from 
       administration_work aw
     group by 
        to_char("DATE", 'MON-YYYY'), id_customer, id_dep
   ) aw on c.id = aw.id_customer
   join (
     select 
       id_customer,  
       id_dep,
       to_char("DATE", 'MON-YYYY') date_activity,
       TRUNC(sum(duration)/60,2) as productive_work
     from 
       productive_work pw
     group by 
       to_char("DATE", 'MON-YYYY'), id_customer, id_dep
     ) pw on c.id = pw.id_customer
           and aw.date_activity = pw.date_activity
   RIGHT OUTER join department d on (d.id = aw.id_dep and d.id = pw.id_dep)
   where c.id = (select id from customer where customer = 'Coffe world')           
   group by aw.date_activity, c.customer, d.department, aw.administration_work, pw.productive_work
   order by aw.date_activity desc, d.department
   ;
```

Comment: No, it wasn't help, still the same result like mine